# Acceso denegado al ejecutar archivo .cmd con C# en windows server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-8.0

Tengo una aplicación web que esta alojada en un servidor IIS7 en un equipo servidor con windows server 2008, la aplicación consiste en ejecutar un archivo .cmd en el servidor, el archivo .cmd tiene una instrucción para reiniciar el equipo servidor, pero no se puede ejecutar ya que  me muestra el siguiente error

```
 System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Acceso denegado
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   en Ted.MNSProject.Reiniciar.Shutdown() en C:\Users\test\Desktop\Soluciones\MNS\Ted.MNS\Ted.MNSProject\Reiniciar.aspx.cs:línea 154
   en Ted.MNSProject.Reiniciar.btnSiReiniciar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Users\test\Desktop\Soluciones\MNS\Ted.MNS\Ted.MNSProject\Reiniciar.aspx.cs:línea 59
```

y este es mi codigo de la aplicacion

```html
       protected void btnSiReiniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Shutdown();

                Log2("MNS OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log2("MNS ERROR  " + ex.ToString());
            }

        }



public void Shutdown()
        { 
            string pathBAT = "C:\\Users\\pc1\\Desktop\\restartWindows.cmd";

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pathBAT);

            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);

        }
```

Comment: no tienes acceso a ese archivo le faltan permisos a IIS para acceder, ademas para que quieres reiniciar todo el servidor desde una aplicacion IIS.

Comment: @MiguelZarate y como le doy permisos para poder tener acceso al archivo?, lo que pasa que se bloquea el servidor y dejan de funcionar unos servicios que tengo y se tiene que reiniciar cada vez que sucede eso

Comment: Lo mejor es que encuentres las causas del bloqueo, porque una vez que se bloquee el servidor no podras ejecutar nada mas, por lo que tu reinicio no sera util

Comment: ¿Has visto el EventViewer?